# How to make lists the same size?

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I want to add 19 lists together and then average over them but they are of unequal length. How do I make then all the same length? i.e. make them all the length of the smallest one.

My lists are called

```
nthrealisation[n_] := RESULTS[[{n}, All]];
```

For each `n` (ranging from 1-19) the lists are different lengths.

```
RESULTS = {};
For[iterator = 1, iterator < 20, iterator++,
 n = 200; m = 200; t = 0;
 results = {{t, n, m}};
 mu = 0.1; nimmig = 1;
 While[t < 1000,
  death = mu*2*n*m;
  birth = mu*(n + m);
  rate = death + birth + nimmig;
  deltaT[r_] := -1/r*Log[RandomReal[]];
  t1 = deltaT[rate];
  t = t + t1;
  rand = RandomReal[]*rate;
  rand1 = RandomReal[];
  rand2 = RandomReal[]*rate;
  rand3 = RandomReal[];
  Which[
   rand <= death,
   Which[
    rand1 <= (n/(n + m)), (n = n - 1) && (m = m),
    If[
     (rand2 > death) && (rand2 <=death + birth) && (rand3 < (m/(n + m))), (n= n) && (m = m + 1), (n = n) && (m = m)
     ];
    True, (n = n) && (m = m - 1)
       If[
        (rand2 > death) && (rand2 <=death + birth) && (rand3 < (n/(n + m))),(n = n + 1) && (m = m), (n = n) && (m = m)
        ];
    ];
   (rand > death) && (rand <= death + birth),
   Which[
    rand1 < (n/(n + m)), (n = n + 1) && (m = m),
    If[
     (rand2 < death) && (rand3 < (m/(n + m))), (n = n) && (m =m - 1), (n =n) && (m = m)
     ];
    True, (n = n) && (m = m + 1)
        If[
        (rand2 < death) && (rand3 < (n/(n + m))), (n = n - 1) && (m = m), (n= n) && (m = m)
        ];
    ];
   True,
   If[
     rand1 <= 1/2, (n = n + 1) && (m = m), (n = n) && (m = m + 1)
     ];
   ];
  results = Append[results, {t, n, m}];
  ];
 AppendTo[RESULTS, results];
 ]

 nthrealisation[n_] := RESULTS[[{n}, All]];
```

Comment: So if the length of the smallest list is 3, then you want entries 4, 5, ... in the other lists to be dropped? If so, try `lists = Table[nthrealisation[n], {n, 19}]; With[{nmin = Min[Length /@ lists]}, Take[#, nmin] & /@ lists]`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I added your code and evaluated. Then I did "Sum[nthrealisation[n],{n,19}]" to add up all the lists but it still says that they are of unequal length @J.M.

Comment: Because I didn't sum the lists yet, and you still haven't answered my question. Use `Total[]` on the result of that last snippet, instead of `Sum[]`.

Comment: Yes, what you assumed is correct. However, I am still very confused as to what you mean. @J.M.

Comment: When you evaluated my last snippet, you got output, yes? After getting that output, type `Total[%]` in a new cell and evaluate that.

Comment: Yes I did. I have done exactly that and still says unequal length @J.M.

Comment: Well, something in your data is making that not work. Since we don't have it, or even a small subset of your data, it's hard to say anything more constructive.

Comment: @J.M. I have attached my coding for you to see :D

Answer (score 2):

```
lists = {{a, b, c}, {w, x, y, z}, {r, s, t, u, v}};
```

To make the elements of `lists` the same length you can use

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
TrimRight[lists]
```

> {{a, b, c}, {w, x, y}, {r, s, t}}

You get the same result using

```
Take[#, Min[Length /@ lists]] & /@ lists (* as suggested by @JM in a comment *)
Take[lists, All, Min[Length /@ lists]]
PadRight[#, Min[Length /@ lists]] & /@ lists
lists[[All, ;; Min[Length /@ lists]]]
```

To get the mean, just use `Mean` on the trimmed list:

```
Mean[TrimRight[lists]]
```

> {1/3 (a + r + w), 1/3 (b + s + x), 1/3 (c + t + y)}

Similarly for `Total`:

```
Total[TrimRight[lists]]
```

> {a + r + w, b + s + x, c + t + y}

**Update:** working with OP's actual data:

```
lists = RESULTS;
Dimensions /@ lists
```

> {{6384, 3}, {5962, 3}, {5867, 3}, {5972, 3}, {5960, 3}, {6088, 
>         3}, {6186, 3}, {6227, 3}, {6161, 3}, {5866, 3}, {6171, 3}, {6191, 
>         3}, {6269, 3}, {6099, 3}, {5987, 3}, {5848, 3}, {6064, 3}, {6156, 
>         3}, {5923, 3}}

```
trimmedlists = lists[[All, ;; Min[Length /@ lists]]];
Dimensions /@ trimmedlists
```

> {{5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 
>         3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 
>         3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 3}, {5848, 
>         3}, {5848, 3}}

```
means = Mean[trimmedlists];
Dimensions@means
```

> {5848, 3}

Note: The function `nthrealisation[n]` wraps the list of interest with `{..}`, e.g.,

```
Dimensions[nthrealisation[1]]
```

> {1, 6384, 3}

So if you want to use the function `nthrealisation` to construct a list of lists, you need to use `nthrealisation[n][[1]]` when you are generating `lists`:

```
lists = Table[nthrealisation[n][[1]], {n, 19}]
```

Alternatively, define your function as

```
nthrealisation2[n_] := RESULTS[[n]]
```

and use

```
lists = Table[nthrealisation2[n], {n, 19}]
```

Comment: I have a very basic understanding of Mathematica, so am unsure of how to implement this into my coding

Comment: @Mlo27, welcome to mma.se.  You can replace `lists` with your `RESULTS`.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. May I add that my lists "nthrealisation[n]" contains approx 6000 elements.

Comment: I have attached my coding for you to see. @kglr

Comment: @Mlo27, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm still slightly confused. Can I not just trim my results using "trimmedlists = lists[[All, ;; Min[Length /@ lists]]];". And then define "nthrealisation[n_]:=trimmedresults[[n]]". Then I can do "Table[nthrealisation[n],{n,19}]" and then add each table together and then divide through? If not, is it possible for you to provide the exact coding I need to use in order to find the average of the 19 realisation? Thanks in advance @kglr

Comment: @Mlo27, "exact code" to get the average of 19 realizations is `Mean[RESULTS[[All, ;; Min[Length /@RESULTS]]]`. If you also need the totals you can use `Total[RESULTS[[All, ;; Min[Length /@RESULTS]]]`.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I'll give that a try tomorrow morning :D

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear quite what the OP seeks, but it makes little sense to trim a list just to make it the length of the shortest list.

I suspect this is what is needed:

```
Mean /@ {{a,b,c}, {d,f,g,h},{j,k,l,m,n,o}}
```

(*

{1/3 (a + b + c), 1/4 (d + f + g + h), 1/6 (j + k + l + m + n + o)}

*)

Comment: I am simulating two coupled populations. Each set of results (I have 19) contain times that an event happens and the occupation in each population. Hence, results are in the form {t,n,m}. However I want to take an average of all the simulation. For example when the first event occurs, second and so on, and then what the occupation number are for these averaged times.